# Equality operator `==` invocation with references of unrelated types while using data_connection_checker package

Tags: flutter, connection, future, flutter-futurebuilder

To check for internet connection i am using data_connection_checker package but it seems that I am not getting how to use it.
I am using following code to check internet connection by calling in initstate

```
 Widget _showDialog(String err,String content ,BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
              title: new Text(err),
              content: new Text(content),
              actions: <Widget>[
                new FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      setState(() {

                      });
                    },
                    child: new Text("Try Again"))
              ]
          );
        }
    );
  }

  Future checkConnection(BuildContext context) async{
    listener = DataConnectionChecker().onStatusChange.listen((status) {
      switch (status){
        case DataConnectionStatus.connected:
          return "DataConnectionState.connected";
          break;
        case DataConnectionStatus.disconnected:
          InternetStatus = "You are disconnected to the Internet. ";
          contentmessage = "Please check your internet connection";
          _showDialog(InternetStatus,contentmessage,context);
          break;
      }
    });
    return await DataConnectionChecker().connectionStatus;
  }
```

But I am also trying to check for internet connection in FutureBuilder widget too.I made following function to call to check

```
Future<bool> internetChecker(BuildContext context) async{
    if( await DataConnectionChecker().hasConnection){
      return true;
        // Future<bool>.value(true);
    }
    else{
      return false;
        // Future<bool>.value(false);
    }
  }
```

But DataConnectionChecker().hasConnection is showing error until i use await before it like above.

FututreBuilder:

```
builder:(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
if(internetChecker(context) == true){
              if(snapshot.hasData){
                if(snapshot.data==null){
                  return _showDialog('Unexpected Error', 'Data was null', context);
                }
                else{
                  return SafeArea(...);
                }
              }
              else{
                return Center(child: Image.asset("assets/images/369.gif",fit: BoxFit.fill,));
              }
            }
            else{
               return _showDialog('No Internet Connection', 'Check your Internet Connection and Try Again!!', context);
            }
          }
        ),
     }
```

I am trying all of this in builder of FutureBuilder.
Now, in if when i write 'internetChecker(context) == true' it shows me this
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

`Equality operator '==' invocation with references of unrelated types.`

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Edit:
Moreover in internetchecker function during debugging i noticed it just jumps the if else condition and doesnot return any thing neither true nor false. I am not getting why.

Please tell me how to solve it or any other efficient way to do it.

Answer (score -3):

You compare 2 element but not a same type. Future < bool > is not same type with bool.

try

```
internetChecker(context).then((value){
value == true ? ...
});
```

Comment: This answer could be a comment, since it don't provide a solution to the question